# jQuery - window visibility API to keep running

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

I am trying to do so my countdown will only count down whenever the window is active, and then stop whenever the window is not active anymore.

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-visibility/blob/master/jquery-visibility.js

```
   $(function() {
    $(document).on({
        'show.visibility': function() {
            setTimeout("runCounter()",1000);
            console.log('The page gained visibility; the <code>show</code> event was triggered.');
        },
        'hide.visibility': function() {
            time = time;
            console.log('The page lost visibility; the <code>hide</code> event was triggered.');
        }
    });
});

    function runCounter() {

        if(time==0){
            $('#counter').html('<button class="butn blue" onclick="<?php echo $creditButtonName; ?>();">Click here to get credited!</button>');
        }
        else {
            $('#counter').html('You must view this advertisement for ' + time + ' more seconds!');
            startBar();                                     
            time=time-1;                
            //setTimeout("runCounter()",1000);

        }


    }
```

How is it possible to do so the jquery visibility API will run not just once, but each second when the page is active - and then trigger another function when the page isn't active?

At this current state, this: `setTimeout("runCounter()",1000);` will only run whenever I go to another window/tab and then go back to the first window. It will not run each second when the window is active.

Comment: No answers? I guess people don't want to support advertising.

Comment: @chrishiestand what do you mean they don't want to support advertising?

Comment: People tend to dislike being forced to watch advertisements. Perhaps that's why nobody has answered?

Comment: @chrishiestand I am not using my script to "force" anyone. The advertisements I am showing, the users agree to view them for a small amount of cash. All I want is to ensure, that my clients ads is being seen, when they are paying people to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, [setTimout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) only runs once.  What I believe you want is [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval), which calls the function again and again, at the interval you specify, until cleared with the clearInterval() function.

The approach I would take would be to create a countdown object, with internal time remaining, interval properties, and pause, resume, countdown and finish methods.

```
function Countdown( time ) {

 var self = this; // self reference

 var time = parseInt( time ) || 10;  // default to 10 s

 var timer = false;

 this.countDown = function() {    
  if ( --time < 1 ) {
   self.finish();
  }
  else {
   // code to update countdown display on page
  }
  return this;
 }

 this.finish = function() {
  this.pause();
  // the code you want to execute when time reaches 0
  return this;
 }

 this.resume = function() {
  if ( !timer ) {
   if ( time > 0 ) {
    timer = setInterval( function() {
     self.countDown();
    }, 1000 );
   }
   else {
    this.finish();
   }
  }
  return this;
 }

 this.pause = function() {
  if ( timer ) {
   clearInterval( timer );
   timer = false;
  }
  return this;
 }

}
```

So all you need to do is create a Countdown object, and bind the pause and resume methods to the page visibility change events.

You could also check the page's visibility status when the Countdown object is created to decide whether or not to start the countdown.